# Hibernate/NHibernate mapping rules

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, orm, nhibernate-mapping, compatibility

I found a good article on `Hibernate` associations mapping (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/associations.html). Could the same rules described in the article be applied to `NHibernate` mapping files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in principle, I think so (haven't read the whole thing, but it looks ok to me).
the [nHibernate docs](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections) contain pretty good explanations as well.